# NoSuchMethodError when upgrading spark to 2.4.5

Tags: apache-spark, version, upgrade

Following an upgrade to the spark version in our project to 2.4.5 (as part of a general 1.5.1 product upgrade), we are getting following error when running the test suites in the scoring-batch module. Our build.gradle file is fairly aligned to that in project example.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.DEFAULT_URL_STREAM_HANDLER_FACTORY_
ENABLED()Lorg/apache/spark/internal/config/ConfigEntry;
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
  at org.scalatest.tools.ConcurrentDistributor.waitUntilDone(ConcurrentDistributor.scala:50)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1299)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:972)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:971)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1474)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:971)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:775)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
  Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.DEFAULT_URL_STREAM_HANDLER_FACTORY_ENABLED()Lorg/apache/spark/interna
l/config/ConfigEntry;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$setFsUrlStreamHandlerFactory(SharedState.scala:165)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:121)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:120)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1115)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:145)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:144)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:141)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$applyModifiableSettings$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:974)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$applyModifiableSettings$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:974)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.applyModifiableSettings(SparkSession.scala:974)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:907)
  at com.quantexa.analytics.test.SparkTestSuite.spark$lzycompute(SparkTestSuite.scala:27)
  at com.quantexa.analytics.test.SparkTestSuite.spark(SparkTestSuite.scala:22)
  at com.quantexa.scb.trade.scoring.batch.utils.ScoringGeneratedDataTestSuite$class.beforeAll(ScoringGeneratedDataTestSuite.scala:38)
  at com.quantexa.scb.trade.scoring.batch.utils.EndToEndNetworkBuildTest.beforeAll(EndToEndNetworkBuildTest.scala:12)
  at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)
  at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
  at com.quantexa.analytics.test.SparkTestSuite.run(SparkTestSuite.scala:19)
  at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is as a result of conflicting spark versions between 2.4.5 and 2.4.6 due to other libraries bringing in 2.4.6. To solve this force the spark libraries to stay fixed at 2.4.5 with the following change in the relevant build.gradle file:

```
provided("org.apache.spark:spark-core_$scalaVersion:$spark"){force = true}
provided("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_$scalaVersion:$spark"){force = true}
provided("org.apache.spark:spark-yarn_$scalaVersion:$spark"){force = true}
provided("org.apache.spark:spark-hive_$scalaVersion:$spark"){force = true}
provided("org.apache.spark:spark-graphx_$scalaVersion:$spark"){force = true}
provided("org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_$scalaVersion:$spark"){force = true}
```